# Flask Flask-Security with GAE ndb?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, flask-security

I am building and hosting my application on the Google App Engine with Python on Flask.
And now I want to use the flask-security extension and realized there isn't much resources to start with under my configuration, which is a bit surprise to me as I thought this stack should be quick common.

On the Flask-Security's Quick Start [Page](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#), examples of SQLAlchemy, MongoDB and Peewee are  provided. However, I cannot find samples of GAE-NDB in particular. If someone can point me out if it is possible to use flask-security on my dev stack, and it would be much appreciated if some examples of how to create `security` object like below sample code in SQLAlchemy

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    pass

# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)
```

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE and my workaround for those of you who have the same question or doubts**

GAE-NDB is not compatible, at least you have to do some extra work, with flask-security. 
Below is the from flask-security [homepage](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/)

> Additionally, it assumes you’ll be using a common library for your database connections and model definitions. Flask-Security supports the following Flask extensions out of the box for data persistence:
>
> - Flask-SQLAlchemy
> - Flask-MongoEngine
> - Flask-Peewee

and my final solution is to use mongodb as my datastore, which is hosted on mongolab. They have free instance for prototyping and development.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a good idea from [gae-init.](http://gae-init.appspot.com/), it is a complete implementation of a web application based on Flask and Google App Engine. Following the documentation and digging a bit in the code will give you a good idea about how things are setup along with lots of good practices and common functionality that every web app requires.

Comment: Thanks topless  :o .....  gae-init is good start point, though I m looking for answer if ndb is compatible with flask-security. The short answer is no, I have switched to mongodb now.